# How can i activate document via vscode extension command?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code extension development,

I want to activate(or open) specific document that is in filesystem.

I tried

```
let testfileURI="c:\\Users\\MKLee\\git\\Jclip-proto-private\\src\\test\\java\\kr\\ac\\jbnu\\jclip\\controller"

vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(testfileURI);
```

and

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open',testfileURI);
```

It doesn't throw any error and do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showSuccessMsg(testfileURI) {
  if (fs.existsSync(testfileURI)) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(testfileURI));
    });
    promise.then(function(value) {
      vscode.window.showTextDocument(value);
    });
  }
}
```

its a little bit complicated